# How does deeper or shallower trees (higher or lower max_depth) affect xgboost model?

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameter

I am doing an xgboost model for landslides assessment and I am using `max_depth` as one of my hyperparameters, but I don't understand how does it affect model analysis if it was high or low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `max_depth` is set to a high value, the model becomes more complex and has the potential to capture intricate patterns in the training data. However, this can also lead to overfitting, and may also consume more memory during training.

Conversely, setting a lower value for `max_depth` results in a simpler model that is less likely to overfit. This can lead to faster training times and may require less memory. However, a model with a low `max_depth` may not capture complex relationships in the data, potentially leading to underfitting.